# Parse public facebook posts with beautifulsoup / python

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to parse facebook posts which are made to a specific topic (like a company or a product). As an example posts from here https://www.facebook.com/search/latest/?q=facebook

I can login to facebook (with python) correctly and I am also able to get the source code of the page which contains the posts I am looking for. After some manual code review I found out that I wanted to get following:

```
<div class="_5pbx userContent" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;&#125;">
    <p>Here is the text of the post I need
    </p>
</div>
```

So I started with beautifulsoup and following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSourceCode.content, 'html.parser')

for msg in soup.find_all('div'):
    print (msg.get('class')
```

As result I get only this ...

```
[u'hidden_elem']
```

Does someone have experience in scraping facebook posts? I only need this for myself and education purposes

Comment: Additionally I tried to do following for testing purposes " print soup.find_all('p') " which only prints following result " [] "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was, that the class I search for was written in an comment. So i hade firstly to search for the div upon the comment, encode it, and create a new soup object. After that was able so select the div I was searching for via the css selector.

```
comment = soup.select('code#u_0_11')
comment_data = comment[0].string.encode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(comment_data, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.select('div._5pbx.userContent')
```

An now I could print it via for:

```
for div in divs:
    p = div.find_all('p')
    print (p[0].text.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code should work

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSourceCode.content, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', class_="_5pbx userContent")
for div in divs:
    p = div.find('p')
    print(p.get_text())
```

Comment: Thank for your response, I tried your code but it doesn't work :( ... so I played around and found something out... 
If I print out "divs" it is empty like "[]" and if I print the type of it, it prints "<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>" that looks good in my opinion?

If i change soup.find_all('div', class_="_5pbx userContent") to soup.find_all('div') I get the same type and a lot of stuff printed out with "print divs"
Can there be a problem finding the class_="_5pbx userContent" div if it is nested? Because its like be on the 5th place in the code (<div><div><div><div><div class=_5pbx..>)

Comment: No, there will be no problem if div is nested.Just make sure that the class is exactly as in source code.